# Get PDFs to open in a separate reader

Tags: windows, browser, pdf

On Ubuntu, Firefox does not open PDFs. Instead, it downloads them and they open in Evince. Is there any way to make Windows behave the same way (for any browser: I use a bunch of different ones on Windows)? I prefer to have PDFs in a separate window. (Unless, perhaps, someone is sticking a PDF in a HTML `frame` or `iframe`, but that's rare.)

Comment: Why not just pick a browser and use the search: [Firefox](http://superuser.com/search?q=%2Bfirefox+%2Bopen+%2Bpdf), [Chrome](http://superuser.com/search?q=%2Bchrome+%2Bopen+%2Bpdf), ...? "Any" browser is not helpful here, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Adobe Reader, then open `Edit`->`Preferences`, select category `Internet` and uncheck `Display PDF in browser`

Answer (score 1):

Disable the feature in your PDF viewing program.  For Adobe Reader, uncheck the "Display PDF in browser" box in the Internet category.  Other readers will have a similar option.

Comment: Tried this. It's not working for Firefox or Opera. I don't know whether I have any other PDF readers installed as browser plugins. I don't think so.

Comment: That *should* work.  When it doesn't then you might also need to disable the plugin in the browser too.  For each browser this is slightly different.  Firefox: Plugins can be disabled from the Add Ons dialog.  Chrome: open up the chrome://plugins link in your browser and disable the PDF plugin.  Internet Explorer: Open the "Manage Add-Ons" dialog from the Tools menu.